Efficient algorithm for A217061

Let $a(n)$ be A217061. Here
$$
a(n) = \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n}\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-m}(n+k-1)!\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}\frac{1}{(k-j)!}\sum\limits_{\ell=0}^{j}\frac{2^{\ell-j}(-1)^{\ell+j}s(n-m-\ell+j, j-\ell)}{\ell!(n-m-\ell+j)!}.
$$
where $s(n,k)$ are (signed) Stirling numbers of the first kind.
Start with vector $\nu$ of fixed length $m$ with elements $\nu_i=1$ (that is, $\nu=\{1,1,\dotsc,1\}$), reserve $t$ as an empty vector of fixed length $m$, set $t:=\nu$ and for $i$ from $1$ to $m-1$, for $j$ from $1$ to $m-i$ consecutively apply
$$
\nu_{j+1} := j\nu_j + \nu_{j+1}, \\
\nu_{j} := j\nu_j + \nu_{j+1}.
$$
We also need to apply $t_{i+1} = \nu_1$ (after ending each cycle for $j$).

I conjecture that after the whole transform
$$
t_n = a(n).
$$
Here is the PARI/GP program to check it numerically:
a(n) = sum(m=1, n, 1/(m-1)!*sum(k=0, n-m, (n+k-1)!*sum(j=0, k, 1/(k-j)!*sum(l=0, j, 2^(j-l)*(-1)^(l+j)*stirling(n-m-l+j, j-l, 1)/(l!*(n-m-l+j)!)))))
upto1(n) = my(v1); v1 = vector(n, i, 1); v2 = v1; for(i=1, n-1, for(j=1, n-i, v1[j+1] += j*v1[j]; v1[j] = j*v1[j] + v1[j+1]); v2[i+1] = v1[1]); v2
test1(n) = upto1(n) == vector(n, i, a(i))

In addition, this question can be rephrased as follows:

Let
$$
R(n, q) = \begin{cases}
1 & \textrm{if } n = 0 \\
R(n-1, q+1) + 2(q+1)!\sum\limits_{j=0}^{q} \frac{R(n-1,j)}{j!} & \textrm{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

I conjecture that
$$
R(n,0)=a(n+1).
$$
Is there a way to prove it?

Where does this sequence come from? Why is it interesting?

As for the first question, see the OEIS entry of this sequence. At least this is interesting because such a complex sum and such a simple algorithm give the same result.
